# Flutter wrong utc time from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, datetime, flutter, utc

I've got a problem with flutter recognizing my `DateTime` as UTC time. Via http request, I am storing some data inside my SQL Server database which contains a UTC `DateTime`. This is done via Entity Framework.

```
var workingTime = new WorkingTime()
{
    StartDateTime = dto.StartDateTime.ToUniversalTime(),
    EndDateTime = dto.EndDateTime.ToUniversalTime(),
    ...
};

await _repository.AddAsync(workingTime);
```

[image]

This looks quiet okay, the request was done at `2020-06-13 01-59-41:690` in Germany, so the stored data is the correct UTC time.

Now I am loading these data in my flutter app and if I debug my app, the loaded `datetime` says, that it is not a UTC time.

[image]

I am not sure, if I store the data wrong, or if I the parsing inside flutter is wrong, but I can't see me doing something wrong here.

Please tell me if you need code or more information.

## Edit

So after a lot of testing, I found out something:

```
Debug.WriteLine(model.EndDateTime.Kind);
```

This prints "Unspecified". It seems like there is something wrong either in storing the DateTime or in reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit about the UTC every time. Indicate to the compiler you want the UTC time.
To get millisecondsSinceEpoch in UTC time:

```
DateTime dateTime=DateTime.now().toUtc();
int epochTime = dateTime.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

To get Datetime in UTC:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch).toUtc();
```

Comment: The problem is, that flutter doesn't recognize the loaded DateTime (from the server) to be a UTC time, so it thinks it is a local time. If I convert the time into UTC, i get '2020-06-12 21-59-41.690' so 2 hours earlier that to real local time

Comment: I wish I could see the code . Otherwise I cant help you.

Comment: What code do you need? On the flutter side, I kust get the dto via a http request. Then I check if the received model.time is a utc time. ```var utcTime = model.date.isUtc;``` which returns false

Comment: Time on your  SQL Server database is stored as INT?  How do you convert  time from http request? how do you represent time on your server? show the response json from server. How you convert json to dto object representing time

Comment: Actually the time is stored as a DateTime inside the database but actually I found something out. Let me update the thread

Comment: I would not  store time as DateTime inside database. That is a no no.Store time as int

Comment: How would you store the DateTime?

Comment: Store as int.    DateTime dateTime=DateTime.now().toUtc();
int epochTime = dateTime.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

Answer (score 0):

Store time as int in database. Milliseconds since epoch time.

```
DateTime dateTime=DateTime.now().toUtc();
int epochTime = dateTime.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Comment: And how do you handle the [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)?

Comment: DateTime class will handle that.

Comment: I still don't see the advantage against DateTime, especially int also does not store TimeZone information

Comment: You will get different values if you store the same time in UTC: DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch  and in local time DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.  So be consistent and in database store time in UTC only.

Comment: So what does it mean?-> that time zones are stored in that int values!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thinking I came along a good method for my case. I ended up implementing an extension method, that converts the Kind of every DateTime stored inside the Database to the UTC Kind when loaded.

Inside the DataContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Convert all DateTimes to UTC
    modelBuilder.TreatDateTimeAsUtc();

}
```

The extension method

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void TreatDateTimeAsUtc(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var dateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
            v => v.ToUniversalTime(),
            v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc));

        var nullableDateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime?, DateTime?>(
            v => v.HasValue ? v.Value.ToUniversalTime() : v,
            v => v.HasValue ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(v.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc) : v);

        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    property.SetValueConverter(dateTimeConverter);
                }
                else if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    property.SetValueConverter(nullableDateTimeConverter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```